# What is the best database for an online Android location app?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am working on Android app for locating food places in my city.
Using Google Map v2 api.

App shows user his current location, and the closest food spots around him.

I want to store location coordinates in an online database, and App should retrieve data
in JSON format from db to phone.
I am familiar with PHP and MySql.

Which database should i use to store locations ?
Is MySql good for that purpose ?
How will i store location data in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are **100%** sure that requirements are not going to change, and you just need to store the coordinates of the points, then yes, go ahead and save the data in a MySQL database, as two double columns.

But if there is even a little chance that the scope can increase, then I'll suggest that you spend some time setting up a PostGIS database and save the data in it as Geometric points.

Most projects suffer from [feature-creep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep), and before you know it, you will have to do Geometric operations in the database, like getting points in a certain polygon, or finding distances and so on. If your data is in a PostGIS database, all of this will be very simple.

Comment: Wow, great answer thanks. there will be more features. map markers, distance to locations ... Will investigate PostGis as you suggested.

Comment: I wonder if these 2 different datapoints and a uid would happily live in Redis.  Another great thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979085/geo-program-design-suggestions-using-redis